# No of Days between two dates in advanced PDF template netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can anybody help in getting difference between two dates in advanced pdf template in netsuite?

Answer (score 1):

```
        <!-- Function -->
        <!-- Calculate Days from a Specific Date --><#function dateDiff date days>
        <#assign timeInMillisecond = (1000 * 60 * 60 *  24 * days) />
        <#assign aDate = date?long + timeInMillisecond?long /><#return aDate?number_to_date>undefined</#function>undefined<!-- Date 

        Vars -->undefined<#assign date_today = .now />undefined<#assign date_ten_days_from_today = dateDiff(date_today, 10) />
```